# Why toggle effect not working for nested div using angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

I have attached the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vd5hE0I8ke1bnGjUNN2W?p=preview). I am unable to access `.gc` and `.mc` element . Although my code is working partially and class `.bc` is working as expected. I am trying to apply toggle effect on them and hierarchy wise

> BroadCategory  > GeneralCategory > MainCategory

Not sure what am I missing in

```
$(element).find('.gc').click( function() {
    alert('GC');
    $(element).find(".mc").slideToggle('200',function() {  
       $(element).find("span").toggleClass('faqPlus faqMinus');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Angular links the BroadCategory div, the GeneralCategory (ng-repeat)elements have not yet been created yet.  So the click handler is never added. 
Add the d-expand-collapse attribute to the .gc element.  You should then see your click alert fire.

```
<div d-expand-collapse ng-repeat="gen in group.items">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is being called before the `ng-repeat` that creates the `.gc` elements. A quick fix would be to wrap the function in a timeout to let it finish rendering. I'm sure there is a better way using some hook in angular, but this will accomplish what you want.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $(element).find('.gc').click( function() {
    alert('GC');
    $(element).find(".mc").slideToggle('200',function() {  
      $(element).find("span").toggleClass('faqPlus faqMinus');
    });
  });
});
```